# Sonata Admin general roles

Tags: symfony, roles, sonata-admin

I wanna use the Role Handler security on my Sonata admin dashboard. I work with Symfony 2.3.

In the doc, I have:

> Each permission is relative to an admin: if you try to get a list in
>   FooAdmin (declared as sonata.admin.demo.foo service), Sonata will
>   check if the user has the `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_EDIT` role.

As I understand, if I have services such as:

- `sonata.admin.article`
- `sonata.admin.user`
- `sonata.admin.tag`

Then I need to create an edit role, being a list of those 3 elements:

`ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ARTICLE_EDIT` and `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_EDIT` and `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_TAG_EDIT`

But I would rather like to create access more generals, for example, in my case, simply do: `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDIT` instead and of a list of three.

Is there a simple way to do this with this bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by overriding the `Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\RoleSecurityHandler` class and `getBaseRole` method:

```
# AppBundle/Security/Handler/MyRoleSecurityHandler.php

namespace AppBundle\Security\Handler;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\RoleSecurityHandler;

class MyRoleSecurityHandler extends RoleSecurityHandler
{

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public function getBaseRole(AdminInterface $admin)
   {
        return 'ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_%s';
   }
}
```

overwrites the sonata service related to this class:

```
# AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    #...

    sonata.admin.security.handler.role:
        class: AppBundle\Security\Handler\MyRoleSecurityHandler
        public: false
        arguments: [@security.context, [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]]
```

remember declare these roles in your hierarchy:

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
    role_hierarchy:
        # ...
        ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_LIST: ~
        ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_SHOW: ~
        ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDIT: ~
        ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DELETE: ~
        # etc.
```

once you assign these roles to the user, finally you can to check:

```
# inside of any admin class

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    if ($this->isGranted('EDIT')) {
       # ...
    }
}
```

> Warning! The previous sonata roles (ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ARTICLE_EDIT, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_EDIT, etc.) it will no work. So you could also override the class and the corresponding service of `sonata-project/user-bundle/Security/EditableRolesBuilder.php` to return only the hierarchy of roles.